# Plop.js How to create a prompt of list of choices with conditions

Tags: plop

I have an object of templates and I want to have a prompt with this list that sends to other prompt based on condition

My object

```js
export const myTempates = {
  endpoint: 'lambda-function-api-endpoint',
  handlerTest: 'handler-test-file',
  handlerIntegrationTest: 'handler-integration-test-file',
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all adding multiple generators will create a list of inputs but if you want a list of inputs in a genertor you can do like this :

To create a prompt list you can use `type: 'list'` with `type: 'input'` and use `Object.values(myTempates)` to get all the templates you have in myTemplates object

To have a prompt based on condition you can use when

```js
plop.setGenerator('myGenerator', {
  prompts: [
    {
      type: 'list',
      name: 'template',
      message: 'Choose a template',
      choices: Object.values(myTempates),
    },
    {
      when(context) {
        return context.template.includes(myTempates.endpoint);
      },
      type: 'input',
      name: 'name',
      message: 'Choose a lambda function name',
    },
    {
      when(context) {
        return context.template.includes(myTempates.handlerTest);
      },
      type: 'input',
      name: 'name',
      message: 'Choose test file name',
    },
    {
      when(context) {
        return context.template.includes(myTempates.handlerIntegrationTest);
      },
      type: 'input',
      name: 'name',
      message: 'Choose integration test file name',
    },
  ],
  actions: [],
});
```